# Solve: $4 \log_5 x- \log_5y =1 \quad \&\quad 5\log_5 x+ 3\log_5 y =14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

Find $x,y$ given:

$$4 \log_5 x- \log_5y =1 \quad \&\quad 
5\log_5 x+ 3\log_5 y =14$$

How do I help my son this assignment? Not so good in maths myself

Comment: What are we supposed to do? to find $x,y$??

Comment: Let $a=\log_5 x $ and $b=\log_5 y$
\begin{eqnarray*}
4a-b=1 \\
5a+3b=14
\end{eqnarray*}
Simultaneous equations ...

Comment: yes. Find x and y

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Put $a = \log_5x, b = \log_5y\implies 4a-b=1 = 5a+3b=14\implies 5a+3(4a-1)=14...$ . Can you finish it ? point is solve for $a$, then for $x$ since $x = 5^a$...

Comment: i am grateful. We can go on from here

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $3$ and adding to the second we get
$$17\log_5 x=17$$ thus we get
$$\log_5 x=1$$ can you go on?

Answer (score 0):

$$4 \log_5 x- \log_5y =1 \quad \&\quad 
5\log_5 x+ 3\log_5 y =14$$

$$\log_5x^4y^{-1}=1 \quad \&\quad \log_5x^5y^3=14$$

$$\implies x^4y^{-1}=5 \quad \&\quad x^5y^3=5^{14} $$

$$\implies  x^{12}y^{-3}=5 \quad \&\quad x^5y^3=5^{14}$$

$$\implies x^{17}=5^{17}\implies x=5 \quad \&\quad 5^5y^3=5^{14}\implies y=5^3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
4 \log_5 x- \log_5y &=1\tag 1 \\ 
5\log_5 x+ 3\log_5 y &=14\tag 2
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying $(1)$ by $3$ and adding $(1)+(2)$ we have
$$17\log_5 x=17\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \log_5 x=1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=5$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $-5$  and $(2)$ by $4$ and adding $(1)+(2)$ we have
$$17\log_5 y=51\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \log_5 y=51/17=3\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y=5^3=125$$